# Python - Matplotlib: normalizing y-axis to show multiples of standard deviation

Tags: python, matplotlib, standards, standard-deviation

I would like to renormalize my y-axis to show my signal in multiples of sigma (standard deviation). For example, one then could say at 50Hz there's a 3 sigma signal while at 3Hz there's a 0.5 sigma signal.

I thought using `plt.yticks()` could be the way to go:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = range(0,50,2)
Y = range(0,50,2)

signal_sigma = np.std(Y)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 25*signal_sigma, signal_sigma))
y_labels = [r"${} \sigma$".format(i) for i in range(0, 26)]
plt.ylabel(y_labels)
plt.show()
```

But this doesn't seem quite right yet. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I would like to do: [What does a 1-sigma, a 3-sigma or a 5-sigma detection mean?](https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/what-does-a-1-sigma-3-sigma-or-5-sigma-detection-mean/) The bit right below the probability table.

Comment: Can't you just plot Y/sigma? Or am I missing something - `plt.plot(X, Y/signal_sigma)`

Comment: @DavidG hmm not quite but I think I found a definition on [here] (https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/what-does-a-1-sigma-3-sigma-or-5-sigma-detection-mean/) below the probability table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the yticklabels which is different than setting the axis label with `plt.ylabel`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1000)
y = 42 * np.random.randn(1000)

signal_sigma = y.std()

num_sigma = 3
sigma_values = np.arange(-num_sigma, num_sigma+1)
yticks = signal_sigma * sigma_values
yticklabels = ['$'+str(k)+'\sigma$' if k != 0 else '$\mu$' for k in sigma_values]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks(yticks, yticklabels)
plt.ylabel('the axis label')
```

[image]

Comment: I see! Thank you very much. But what if the signal is bigger than 3 sigma? Then this would fail right? Could you include this (probability) normalization in your code? Right below the probability table (https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/what-does-a-1-sigma-3-sigma-or-5-sigma-detection-mean/) I thought of using scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x) to calculate P(Z). Would that be a way to do it?

Comment: You can just adjust `num_sigma` to get more values.

Comment: yes I know but I don't know if your answer (or what I initially thought would be the way) is what we see there on the link. Has it the same meaning? So no need to define `mu = np.mean(Y), Z = abs(Y-mu)/signal_sigma, P_of_Z = norm(mu, signal_sigma).cdf(Z)` and then divide Y by this number?

Comment: ...I get a 13 sigma value for my highest peak with your code :) and > 4sigma is already 100%